# odoo 12 custom module menu not showing

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

Hello i am new with odoo and having problem with it's docs. i tried to ask in odoo help but can't seems to be able to so i put it here. i followed odoo docs to create a custom module and still stuck on action and menu steps. i followed the guide thoroughly and tried to use same var name. but the result still same and app menu button wont show up. but the guide said that user would be able to see and modify the records

[image: mo]

i 've been tinkering with this problem for 3+ hour and still stuck.

here's the doc i followed [Odoo 12 docs](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/howtos/backend.html#actions-and-menus)

and here additional info on code that supposedly used in the section (?)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>

    <!-- window action -->
    <!--
        The following tag is an action definition for a "window action",
        that is an action opening a view or a set of views
    -->
    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="course_list_action">
        <field name="name">Courses</field>
        <field name="res_model">openacademy.course</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        <field name="help" type="html">
            <p class="oe_view_nocontent_smiling_face">Create the first course
            </p>
        </field>
    </record>

    <!-- top level menu: no parent -->
    <menuitem id="main_openacademy_menu" name="Open Academy"/>
    <!-- A first level in the left side menu is needed
            before using action= attribute -->
    <menuitem id="openacademy_menu" name="Open Academy"
                parent="main_openacademy_menu"/>
    <!-- the following menuitem should appear *after*
            its parent openacademy_menu and *after* its
            action course_list_action -->
    <menuitem id="courses_menu" name="Courses" parent="openacademy_menu"
                action="course_list_action"/>
    <!-- Full id location:
            action="openacademy.course_list_action"
            It is not required when it is the same module -->

</odoo>
```

Comment: Does the model `openacademy.course` has access rights at this stage of the tutorial? If not that could be the issue. Just create some access rights like in [Building a module](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/howtos/backend.html#security)

Comment: no it doesnt. so am i supposed to not be able to test the app button for module until that stage of tutorial ?

Comment: It was possible until Odoo 12. But the change to the admin user (split into odoobot and admin) made it a bit difficult.

Comment: so i should add new access right for administrator every time i made a models ?
and is there any difference between administration setting and access right ? 
thank you for explaining it.

Comment: Please read that up in the documentation. The admin user once had all rights, it was the so called superuser. That changed with the introduction of odoobot which now is the superuser. The admin now needs access rights like every other user, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to create access rights CSV in module like this

```
id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlinnk
id,name,model_openacedemy_course,anygroup,1,1,1,1
```

Comment: it worked, so this access right work like permission to access and/or modify the models. Thank you for your help